# How to automatically append/prepend specific keywords when searching with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

While researching/learning/troubleshooting I often perform dozens of searches in a row containing several of the same keywords.

**How can I get Google Chrome to remember the 'root words' of my search so I only need to enter the ones that change?**

For example, when researching a product I might search

- nike free rn distance best price
- nike free rn distance reviews
- nike free rn distance problems
- nike free rn distance near me
- etc.

I would like to somehow set 'nike free rn distance' (the subject of my search) as the 'always include' keywords, and then only enter the trailing keywords. For example, if I type 'vs asics' in the Chrome address bar, I would like the search query sent to the provider to be 'nike free rn distance vs asics'.

I realize that I can use the back button and edit my search, however, often I've lost/closed the first tab already.

I could add a custom search engine, however, that's even more work than retyping the terms.

I am looking for a solution that use Google Chrome with Google's search engine, however, I would be interested in other ideas as well.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment so I can improve my question?

Comment: @karel thanks for the feedback. I've reworded the title slightly to emphasize that I'm looking for Chrome functionality when interacting with the search engine.

Comment: I am also interested in this - but appending to exclude/include ie `-site:pinterest.com` to always exclude pinterest results. One of the concerns is where it would be appended : `nike free best price` and `best price nike free` return slightly different results.

Comment: Close voters: As I read it, this question is on-topic because it's asking about *changing the behavior of the Chrome Browser*, e.g., "How can I get Google Chrome to remember the 'root words'..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy method:

1. Write out the selection you wish to repeat ("nike free rn distance") in any text field.
2. Select this text and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>C</kbd> to copy it.
3. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>V</kbd> to paste it and then type the rest of your query.
4. Repeat as necessary for the remained of your queries.

Most other possible solutions will require some sort of hotkey combination to insert the desired text, and this method has the advantage of being flexible and easy to implement without any additional software or configuration necessary.

Want to switch between a few different primary search phrases? List them on separate lines in a Notepad window set against the edge of your screen, then select and copy them as necessary.

**Update: Less simple way, addressing need to use clipboard normally**

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261505/autohotkey-paste-write-simple-line-of-text-with-keyboard-shortcut

Using AutoHotKey you can assign hotkey combinations to paste specific phrases, regardless the state of the clipboard.

> Press WINKEY + ALT + C to paste "Some random text"

```
#!c::
  SendInput, Some random text
Return
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already do this sometimes, however, it doesn't work very well for me because I frequently use my clipboard for other cutting and pasting and the 'research sessions' can go on for days or longer sometimes.

Comment: AutoHotkey can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261505/autohotkey-paste-write-simple-line-of-text-with-keyboard-shortcut

Comment: While the plain copy-paste method doesn't work for me, I will be creating an AHK script that can copy-paste several custom clipboard slots... or perhaps find a clipboard manager that can do the equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, music2myear was correct in his answer. Copy and paste is the easiest way to do something like this.

There are plenty of different options, though. You could make a hotstring so whenever you type `nike`, it automatically replaces it with `Nike Free RN Distance`

```
:*:nike::Nike Free RN Distance
```

You could make a hotkey that pastes a pre-defined search:

```
F1::SendInput, Nike Free RN Distance
```

You could go deeper and make a hotkey that pops up an input box so you can type your phrase, then use a different hotkey to paste it whenever you want. This keeps your clipboard from being taken up.
In this example, F2 lets you set your phrase and F1 opens chrome, waits 2 seconds, then sends that phrase to the search bar. You can add whatever you need past that.

```
F2::InputBox, searchPhrase, Search Phrase, Enter a search phrase.

F1::
    Run, Chrome.exe
    Sleep, 2000
    SendInput, % searchPhrase
return
```

Let me know if this answers your question.